# Sharepoint 2010 Master Page without Designer

Tags: 2010

I'm updating a site that has designer disabled, but I need to make changes to the master page. I would prefer to upload a new master page and apply that. I can upload it, but I can't find an option in site settings to allow me to apply it to a page? Am I missing some permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling the Publishing features on the site collection and site will give you the page on Site Settings to set the master page.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.. is this something the site admin would have to do? Or can I do it as an owner? still all new to me and I feel  like I'm drinking out of a firehose.

Comment: Do you have site collection admin privileges? From the Site Actions menu, select Site Settings.  Look for the Site Collection Administration section.

Comment: I don't, but it would be something i would have to ask the site collection admin to do?

Comment: Yes, in order to activate the publishing infrastructure, you would need to ask the site collection administrator.  If that is already activated, you can activate the publishing feature on the Site Features on the Site Settings page. You only need to be the owner/administrator of the individual site for this part.

Comment: I've made the request to the site collection admin. When this is on, will my only option be to change the master page for the entire site? Or is there a way to assign a master page to an individual page?

Answer (score 0):

I think that in 2010 you could still navigate to this url  `http://spserver/sites/thesite/_layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx` and change the masterpage even on non-publishing sites. In 2013 AFAIK this is no longer possible

Comment: Thanks, i tried the URL directly but got an error..

Comment: Then you need to activate publishing as John says.